# How to check if there is a Element Exits in that website

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

```
try
{
    chromeDriver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[11]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/img").Click();
    try
    {
        if (chromeDriver.FindElementByLinkText("TĂNG LIKE CHO BÀI VIẾT").Displayed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Like Fanpage");
        }
        if (chromeDriver.FindElementByLinkText("TĂNG LƯỢT THEO DÕI").Displayed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Follow");
        }
        if (chromeDriver.FindElementByLinkText("TĂNG LIKE CHO FANPAGE").Displayed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("BaiViet");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

This is my code but it not work. I try to find 3 link texts and if it exits, I will do something. For example, showing a MessageBox. Can anyone help me?

```
<span class="font-18 font-bold b200 block-text">TĂNG LIKE CHO BÀI VIẾT</span>
<span class="font-18 font-bold b200 block-text">TĂNG LIKE CHO FANPAGE</span>
<span class="font-18 font-bold b200 block-text">TĂNG LƯỢT THEO DÕI</span>
```

Example:

[image: Picture Here : Example with text " TĂNG LIKE CHO BÀI VIẾT "]

Comment: please add relevant html or the url of the page

Comment: ok i will edit it now

Comment: I have add can you help me :3 thanks

Comment: Those empty `catch` clauses makes it impossible to detect errors. Better get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try get the number of `elements` matching  and then check if the count is >0.

```
chromeDriver.FindElementsByLinkText("TĂNG LIKE CHO BÀI VIẾT").Count();
```